# telugu text using json

Tags: android, json, translation, android-fonts

Is it possible to retrieve text written in telugu from the server for use in application. I have used the below format for Json. It is giving me error in some symbols at the logcat of the avd. If not which would be suitable for getting such kind of text.

```
{
"contacts": [
    {
            "id": "c200",
            "name": "అశ్విని",
            "email": "అశ్విని@అశ్విని.అశ్విని",
            "address": "అశ్విని",
            "gender" : "అశ్విని",
            "phone": {
                "mobile": "అశ్విని",
                "home": "అశ్విని",
                "office": " రేవతి"
            }
    },
    {
            "id": "c201",
            "name": "అశ్విని ram",
            "email": "అశ్విని@అశ్విని.అశ్విని",
            "address": "అశ్విని",
            "gender" : "అశ్విని",
            "phone": {
                "mobile": "అశ్విని",
                "home": "అశ్విని",
                "office": "అశ్విని"
            }
    }
]
}
```

The following is the code i used to retrieve data

```
public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();           

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
}
```

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: Error parsing data org.json.JSONException:   A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 1 of ÿþ
{��
10-31 17:29:11.821: E/JSON Parser(459): ��
10-31 17:29:11.821: E/JSON Parser(459): �� �� �� �� ��"��c��o��n��t��a��c��t��s��"��:�� ��
[��
10-31 17:29:11.821: E/JSON Parser(459): ��                                                                 This is one part of the error i am recieving

Comment: @SRINIVASRAO can you please paste the code you are using at server side for retrieving the data because i need to implement same thing in my script

Comment: @AnswerMe I did not get you

Comment: i am trying to retrieve telugu from server just like you in android ia m using same code but server side some error is there thats why i am asking about server side code

Comment: Do you have a problem in the code for retrieving or json. Once check the JSON format using www.jsonlint.com

Comment: i had no problem in json i have checked it

Comment: @SRINIVASRAO  when i try to retrieve data from json it is giving me &#3112;&#3134; &#3114;&#3143;& this instead of telugu data but when i post url of my phpfile in my browser it is showing properly telugu font there

Comment: @SRINIVASRAO you have defineany json parser class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use NTR.TTF font in the assets folder and should change the line below

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 8000);
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON content uses UTF-8 as default character set (see the RFC 4627, chapter 3). You have to make sure that the server returns a response with the right encoding AND to explicitly use the UTF-8 encoding for the stream reader:

```
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(instream, "UTF-8"), 8000);
```

Comment: I used UTF-16 instead of UTF-8. I could see the text in logcat. When coming to emulator I am getting rectangular boxes as output.

Comment: when coming to device it is giving force close.

Comment: Convert your UTF16 text to UTF8 before sending.